# Why can't Xubuntu 12.04.2 connect to my hidden WPA/WPA2 personal protected wifi network?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, broadcom

I can connect to wi-fi networks that don't have any security without an issue, but when I try to connect to my home wi-fi, I cannot connect.
After a failed attempt to connect, I notice that my computer can see my wi-fi, and it shows that a good signal can be seen, but I still can't connect. All attempts fail in Ubuntu

I can connect properly and have no issues in Win 8.

The wi-fi is a hidden SSID that is WPA/WPA2 Personal protected.
The driver I am using is the Broadcom 802.11 STA Wireless driver, and the wi-fi receiver is a BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since I took my PC networking classes (and I'm no expert), but it sounds odd that your computer sees a hidden network. Have you tried (just for giggles) re-enabling SSID broadcast on your router, connecting your computer to your network, and then disabling SSID broadcast again to hide your network and see if it retains the connection?